# python 3 figures freeze on ubuntu

Tags: matplotlib, python-3.6

I have  a very strange bug. When opening figures in python, if I hover the mouse cursor above the figure toolbar, everything freezes for about a minute. 
I tried:
1. Both from Spyder and using python from bash. 
2. Using tkAgg as well as WX and Qt5Agg. By setting before plotting: ,e.g., matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')

The behavior was similar in all cases. 
Would appreciate any advice here. My OS is Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you have the chance to try on a different system where it works and report about the differences in versions or other particularities. This is a very strange behaviour indeed and it's probably not possible to detect where it comes from with the information currently provided.

Comment: Thanks, as you said this is quite unusual. I tried it myself on a windows system as well as on a Centos server I have access to and as you can imagine the plotting worked as it usually does and I could not reproduce this bug in these cases. I also found no mention of such problems in forums/google etc.

I'll be glad to supply more relevant information or make some tests by switching packages/definitions if anybody can recommend steps such as these